# Close Vote not reflected on Closing

Tags: bug, review

I am reviewing the Close votes. I came across a question, so I thought it should be closed. I was checking the existing close vote, the number in indicator is shown with `Off Topic radio` but when clicked on radio button, it is not reflected which option from Close vote is selected. I am using Chrome 33 on Windows 7, if it matters.

See below attached images:

[image: Issue Image 1]

[image: Issue Image 2]